# 2013 Dart SXT Clunking/Grinding, Front Right

Tags: engine, noise, suspension, dodge, grinding

I own a 2013 Dart SXT, 140k miles.

I typically do all my own maintenance, so most of the car is in decent shape.

However, for the first time I took my car to a shop to get an alignment + 2 front tires. About 2 days after this service, a new issue manifested.

The shop screwed a few things up. Lugs are torn apart, and I can't get the front right off. They put the lugs on with an air gun, without starting them by hand. They ugga dugga'd the shit out of them and one's cross threaded.

So with context out of the way, onto the noise.

It comes from the front right, and can be felt by the passenger in the floorboard area when it's happening.  It happens at idle, in any gear including park and neutral. Turning the wheel does not make it any better or worse. However, doing anything that shifts the weight of the car forward makes it worse, with downshifting being the worst.

It changes with engine RPM. At idle (~700 RPM) it's a steady clunking.  Downshifting from say 3rd to 2nd will cause it to almost become a grinding sound. Handling is not affected at all. It cannot be heard while accelerating because the weight of the car is shifted back.

Things I've checked:

- Engine Mounts
- Tire has clearance from fender liner
- Tire does not rub on suspension
- Wheel bearing is good, but the issue's also while parked so I believe this is ruled out
- CV Joints appear fine, but the issue's also while parked so I believe this is ruled out
- Belts do not appear to have any wear outside of what's normal for a 140k serpentine
- Pulleys do not seem loose, alternator is firmly in place
- Fluids are all good
- No holes in engine block (lol)

I'm at a loss here.

Comment: How did you check the motor mounts? What you describe sounds very much like you have a bad one.

Comment: Only way I know how, had someone control the throttle while I visually checked for movement. I didn't see anything abnormal, but if there's a different way to check I'm all ears!

Comment: You should watch for movement while someone puts it in gear from forward to reverse, then back again (foot on brake pedal, of course). It may take several attempts in shifting to see movement.

Comment: Alright, I'll do that. Thanks for your help, I'll be back with more info

Comment: I've done the test you recommended and there was minimal movement when changing gears back & forth. Motor shifted _slightly_  forward/backward.

Comment: Not sure where you'd go from here, though I wouldn't leave out the possibility there's something wrong with the engine or transmission. Since the noise isn't dependent upon movement of the vehicle, I think the suspension is eliminated (as you suggested). This almost completely excludes what was done at the shop with the new tires.

Comment: i also DIY but at times a pro shop is needed + surely not the one that caused issues!

Comment: Took it to two shops and an independent mechanic. Nobody seems to be able to find it.  The independent noted that one of the front struts it going out, so we'll be replacing both fronts and hopefully tracking down this other issue.